# NOW() in php displaying server time

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp, dreamweaver

```
$query = "INSERT INTO reviews (name, mail, review, date_timestamp, time_timestamp)" . "VALUES ('$reviewer_name', '$reviewer_mail', '$reviewer_review', NOW(), NOW())";
```

NOW() function is displaying time of different zone.How to change it to local time.

Comment: Hi Zeratops..SET is not working in my php code

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the time zone so that the Time will be displayed based on the timezone you set in the function.

Define server timezone and server date format according to your preferences

```
/* server timezone */
define('CONST_SERVER_TIMEZONE', 'UTC');

/* server dateformat */
define('CONST_SERVER_DATEFORMAT', 'YmdHis');
```

**Function:**

```
function now($str_user_timezone,
       $str_server_timezone = CONST_SERVER_TIMEZONE,
       $str_server_dateformat = CONST_SERVER_DATEFORMAT) {

  // set timezone to user timezone
  date_default_timezone_set($str_user_timezone);

  $date = new DateTime('now');
  $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($str_server_timezone));
  $str_server_now = $date->format($str_server_dateformat);

  // return timezone to server default
  date_default_timezone_set($str_server_timezone);

  return $str_server_now;
}
```

Reference: http://www.pontikis.net/tip/?id=18

Comment: Hi Naresh Thanks for your help.. but since i am using NOW() function I cant use the above..

Comment: See Example One from my answer

Comment: @PraneethAlaghari. If so you face any error in this development let me know over here. We shall try to solve it.

Comment: Still facing same problem

Comment: @PraneethAlaghari. What problem you face still

Comment: I pasted the Example 1 of yours exactly above the code and it is displaying error

Comment: Try the example three. This May make the trick for you.

Comment: I tried but no difference

Comment: @PraneethAlaghari. You need to change the MYSQL time format or what..

Comment: @PraneethAlaghari. Check now i have updated the answer